# Passing data into a React component within existing app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I have an existing PHP app which manages products. Each products can have multiple images. Currently the process of adding or removing images is all handled via PHP server side and therefore requires a page load on each action.

As this is a large existing app I'm looking to make improvements throughout and one of these is replacing this image adding/removing section with a react component.

So, I've done exactly that. I've created a component called ImageManager and rendered it into a div with an id.

editProduct.html.twig

```
<div id="image-manager" data-js-images="{images: ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg']}"></div>
```

app.js

```
// Grab element & props
const element = document.getElementById('image-manager');
const props = element.dataset;

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(<ImageManager {...props} />, element);
```

Simple stuff so far. Here's my component...
ImageManager.js

```
import React, {Fragment, useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const ImageManager = ({jsImages}) => {

    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

    // When jsImages changes
    useEffect(() => {
        setImages(jsImages);
    }, [jsImages]);

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className="row">
                {images.map((img, idx) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={idx} className="col-2">
                            <img src={img}/>

                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => {
                                // Remove it
                                const imagesCopy = [...images];
                                imagesCopy.splice(idx, 1);
                                setImages(imagesCopy);
                            }}>Remove</button>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default ImageManager;
```

This all works great, however... the problem I'm having is that new images are added and handled outside of this component by some regular non-react JS. There's a button elsewhere no the page that handles the image upload and returns the new filename from the server.

So my question is, how do I let my ImageManager component know that there's a new image? It seems that changing the "data-js-images" attribute isn't picked up by the component. I'm guessing that this is only read once and if updated then nothing happens.

If I re-render the component and just merge in my new image then pass that to the "data-js-images" attribute then it works fine, but I feel re-rendering an entire components isn't the "right" way of doing this?

Just to be clear, there is no top level component or anything like that.
There's just an app.js file and a bunch of HTML.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Not sure if what I will be proposing is effecient or not, but since you said that new images are handled in vanilla js, why don't you try to handle the change of the images event in there and based on that even render your react component?

Comment: I did actually implement it this way so that when a new image was added it would effectively destroy the existing div and re-render the component from fresh. It does work but this just feels a bit wrong. I appreciate there's no real need to be ultra picky considering what I'm trying to achieve, I just want to be sure that I'm doing it the right way.

Comment: in the react component you used useEffect (even if it isn't working properly as the answer explained correctly) which just re-renderes the component every time your images change. So either way you would re-render your component. It's something totally fine to do in react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The useEffect hook isn't used here, because you only render the component once and dont change the props. You should watch the html element with the data attribute and when it changes you should update the components props.

You could use the MutationObserver constructor with that e.g.

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {
    // Do something when the element changes
});

observer.observe(element, {
    attributes: true
});
```

Haven't tested it myself but it should work.
Else have a look at [this](http://%20https://thewebdev.info/2021/03/03/how-to-watch-for-dom-changes-with-javascript/) atricle

Comment: I've tried it and it does work but it means my component has to handle the change of data in two directions i.e. component makes a change (e.g. remove image) and external app makes a change (e.g. add image). So if my component removes an image, this triggers a state update to "images", which in turn updates the div "data-js-images" attr, which in turn triggers the observer, which calls "setImages" state update again. I guess I'm looking for a way where I can have a single data object and just manipulate that?

Comment: If your component removes an image directly update data-js-images ( plus for something else with your database for example) and not your components state. That way you can handle the data-js-images update and it in turn triggers the useEffect hook. I know this may seem like a detour, but your component only gets rerendered once. This way you only have to manipulate data-js-images.

Comment: That makes so much more sense than what I was doing! It actually works really well, thank you!